# Storing a persistent CLLocation

Tags: objective-c, iphone, persistence, core-location

I think I am missing something obvious somewhere.
I have a (CLLocation *)lastqueriedlocation defined in the header as a property and synthesized.  I want to updated it in locationManager:didUPdateToLocation:fromLocation:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

    CLLocationDistance dist = [lastQueriedLocation getDistanceFrom:newLocation];
    if (dist>1000) {
        lastQueriedLocation = newLocation;
        [self reSearch:lastQueriedLocation];
    }

    if ([resultArray count] > 0) {
        [self findAndDisplayNearestLocation:location];
    }   
}
```

lastQueriedLocation is alloced and init'd in viewDidLoad.

The issue is that of course `lastQueriedLocation = newLocation;` results in an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. So what is the correct approach to persisting the lastQueriedLocation ?

If it helps make the problem more concrete - reSearch is calling a web service fetching POI within 2km of the location - so I only want to do it when we have moved 1km ... but I still want to keep the accuracy at best so I can highlight the nearest, scroll the map etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just setting the iVar rather than the synthesised property, which means newLocation doesn't get retained by the property.

Replace `lastQueriedLocation = newLocation;` with:

```
[self setLastQueriedLocation:newLocation];
```

Or, if you'd rather use dot-notation:

```
self.lastQueriedLocation = newLocation;
```